# How to make a modal visible in a tab where tab is not active

Tags: css, angular, tabs, bootstrap-5, ngx-bootstrap

I am using [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/modals?tab=overview) tabset but I think this would apply to all bootstrap tabs.

```
<tabset>
<tab class='active'>
<angular-modal-component> </angular-modal-component>
</tab>
<tab>
<modal2> </modal2>
</tab>
</tabset>
```

`<angular-modal-component>` modal works fine as `display: block;` in place for the active tab. However, this is not the case for `<modal2>` modal. The backdrop shows but modal itself is not visible as `display: none` is in place for the tab is **not** `active`. Is there a way to get around this issue without moving the `<modal2>` outside of the tab?

Basically what I am asking is 'is there a way to display modal in content that is display:none? If I change this obviously I see the tab content as well so which is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a workaround for this problem, but the solution is:

```
.tab-content > .tab-pane.active {
  visibility: visible;
}
.tab-content>.tab-pane {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.modal2-clasas {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Not a good one. When `display: block` those elements will still take space on DOM but not visible. The layout will be weird.